# Modifying an array from another function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Here is my `main` function:

```
main(){

    int *seats[50] = {0};
    char x;

    do{
        printf("A-Add Reservation\tC-Cancel Reservation\n");
        scanf("%c", &x); 
    } while(x != 'a' && x != 'c');

    switch(x){
    case 'a':
        addRes(&seats); 
        break;
    default: 
        break;
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass `seats[]` into the `addRes()` function so I can modify it within `addRes()`. Here is the function:

```
void addRes(int **seats[]){
    int s, i, scount=0, j=0, k=0, yourseats[]={0};
    printf("How many seats do you require? ");
    scanf("%i\n", &s);
    for(i=0;i<=sizeof(*seats);i++){
        if(*seats[i] == 0)
            scount++;
    }
    if(scount >= s){
        for(i=0;i<=s;){
            if(*seats[i] == 0){
                yourseats[j]=i;
                *seats[i]=1;                
                i++; j++;
            }
            else i++;
        }
        printf("Your seat numbers are: \n");
        while(k < j){
            printf("%i\n", yourseats[k]); 
            k++;
        }   
    }
    else {
        printf("Sorry, there are not enough seats available.\n");
    }
}
```

It compiles with the warnings:

```
Line 15 (*seats[i]=1;) Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast.  
Line 53: (addRes(&seats);) Passing argument 1 of 'addRes' from incompatible pointer       type.
Line 3: (void addRes(int ** seats[]){) Expected 'int ***' but argument is of type  'int *(*)[50]'.
```

On running the program it gets to

```
How many seats do you require?
```

and does nothing after entering a value.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why `main()`? At least it should be `int main()`.

Comment: But why is that? Most programs I have seen are just `main()`.

Comment: Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) and also [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fmainf.htm) one.

Comment: C defaults to `int` if you don't use a return type or if you don't type your arguments. That's true for K&R style but it could vary between compilers, and some might (and should!) complain about it. Be safe, make it `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declaration `int **seats[]` in function parameter is == `int ***seats`, and this means type of `*seats[i]` is `int*` and you are assigning a number to it, that is incompatible type error:

```
*seats[i] = 1; 
  ^         ^ int  
  |        
    int* 

incompatible types
```

Next in  `addRes(&seats);`

`seats` in *array of pointer* its type if `int*[50]` that `&seat` is *pointer of array* and type of `&seat` is `int*(*)[50]` Where as function argument type is `int ***`, so again type incompatible error.
Notice you are also getting a reasonable error message from compiler: `Expected 'int ***' but argument is of type 'int * (*)[50]'.`

**Suggestion:**

As I can see in your code, you don't allocate memory for `seats[i]` in your function `addRes()` and So as I understand you not need to declare `seat[]` array as array of pointers but you need simple array of int.

Change declaration in main():

```
int *seats[50] = {0};
```

should be just:

```
int seats[50] = {0};
 // removed * before seats
```

Next just pass `seats[]`  array's name to `addRes()` function where declaration of function should be

```
addRes(int* seats)

or  addRes(int seats[])
```

it make your work pretty simple in function `addRes()` you can access its elements as `seats[i]` ( and it no need to use extra `*` operator).

**Length of array:**

One more conceptional problem in your code that you are using `sizeof(*seats)` to know the length of array. Its wrong! because in `addRes()` function `seats` is not more an array but a pointer so it will give you the size of address ( but not array length).
And yes to inform about size of `seats[]` in `addRes()` function send an extra parameter called length, so finally declare `addRes()` as follows (read comments):

```
void addRes(int seats[], int length){
     // access seat as 
     //  seat[i] = 10;
     // where i < length 
}
```

Call this function from main() as follows:

```
addRes(seats, 50);
  // no need to use &
```

One more problem that presently you are not facing but you will encounter soon as you will run you code that scanf() need extra <kbd>enter</kbd> in function `addRes()`. To resolve it change: `scanf("%i\n", &s);` as `scanf("%i", &s);` no need of extra `\n` in format string in scanf().

Comment: Thank you! That has made things clear. I will try out passing in the length..so I would pass in `sizeof(seats)` for the length parameter for example?

Comment: @petehallw `sizeof(seats)` will pass the size in bytes which is 50 * 4 (if you are on a 32 bit machine) 200, you need to pass `sizeof(seats)/sizeof(int)` which is 50.

Comment: @petehallw yes from main you can pass length as Nobilis suggesting

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That's why I have written , *if you are satisfied with it* , that says it all. He is free to choose among them , accepting an answer after the problem is resolved of course, makes the post complete and better .

Comment: Both answers have helped me understand what's wrong so I can't choose one in particular

Answer (score 4):

```
int *seats[50] = {0};
```

This is an array of integer pointers, all you need is an actual array so drop the `*` resulting in `int seats[50] = {0};`.

Also your function signature for an array is wrong, `void addRes(int seats[])` will do fine.

Finally, to pass an array to that new signature, you can pass the array directly without any unary address-of operators (arrays will decay to a pointer when passed as an argument to a function):

```
addRes(seats);
```

Also as pointed out, when assigning to an array element, you need to drop the `*`:

```
seats[i]=1;
```

Is more than enough. Same goes for the `if` statements and the like where you do a comparison against an array element.

Regarding your `addRes` function:

```
for(i=0;i<=sizeof(*seats);i++)
```

You will only get the size of the pointer this way, which on a 32bit machine is 4. This trick will not work on an array passed to a function. You will need to pass the array separately.

You can fix it in the following way:

1. Change the function signature of address to this:

   - `void addRes(int seats[], int size)`
2. Pass the size in one of the following ways in main:

   - Directly:   `addRes(seats, 50);`
   - Indirectly: `addRes(seats, sizeof(seats)/sizeof(int));`

Note that the above only works on **local** to the scope of this function arrays, it won't work on an array you've obtained as an argument to a function (or dynamically allocated arrays).

Another issue is to do with `scanf`, you should drop the `\n`. Use `scanf("%i", &s);`

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. So I understand when passing the array it becomes a pointer automatically? My program still does nothing after asking for a value however. :S

Comment: @petehallw Hey, I noticed an issue with `scanf`, it was causing the program to loop forever, please see the edit to my answer for the solution.

Comment: Another silly mistake on my part, this was annoying me for a while! Thanks again

Comment: Nobilis: soon remove this line from your answer *`there's no such format specifier as %i`*  (else people will down-vote you) its in C, yes! give it a try!..

Comment: @Nobilis Very nice, its very good that you knows how to explore things. Impressive. And as I can notice you are  improving your answers too. You deserve good votes keep it up.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks :) Actually it was an oversight on my part, I noticed it was in all the references where I supposedly had looked, so completely my fault.